# I want to make postfix function, do I add which case?

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to make postfix function. But If I execute this program, it becomes infinite loading. I think I have enough case classification.  So, I don't know which conditions to add more cases, Please let me know what I missed

```
void toPostfix() {
    /* infixExp pointer which read one bye on character */
    char *exp = infixExp;

    /* variable for storing char temporarily */
    char x; 
    
    while (*exp != '\0') //iteration 
    {
        if (getPriority(*exp) == operand) // if it is operated
        {
            charCat(exp); //put into postfixExp.
        }
        else 
            if (getPriority(*exp) == rparen) { /* In the case of')', the operator is subtracted from the postfixstack until'(' appears and put into postfixExp*/
                while (getPriority(postfixStack[postfixStackTop]) != lparen) {
                    x = postfixPop(); // subtract operator from postfixstack
                    charCat(&x);//put in postfixExp
                }

                postfixPop(); //The'(' brackets are removed from postfixstack.
            } else { /*If the operator you are trying to put in postfixstack has a lower priority than postfixStack[postfixStackTop]. After subtracting postfixStack[postfixStackTop], put it in postfixExp and enter postfixstack*/
                while (getPriority(postfixStack[postfixStackTop]) >= getPriority(*exp)) {
                    x = postfixPop();// Subtract operator from postfixstack.
                    charCat(&x);// put it in postfixExp
                
                }

                postfixPush(*exp); // Put the operator in postfixstack.
            }      
            
            exp++; //exp has the address value of infixExp, so increase the address value by 1 byte.
    }

    while (postfixStack[postfixStackTop] != '\0') {
        x = postfixPop();
        charCat(&x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including a complete program that can be compiled and executed, sample input that reproduces the problem, expected output, and observed output or behavior.

Comment: Try [debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)... Have you read the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)?

Comment: While editing your code i've seen you've got dangling else problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else
When you write nested if statements always indent properly and never miss any braces!

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
            while (getPriority(postfixStack[postfixStackTop]) >= getPriority(*exp))
```

a line

```
          if (postfixStack[postfixStackTop] != '(')
```

is missing, because if there's a parenthesis operator at the stack top, no operator is allowed to be popped from postfixstack in the `while` loop, independently of its priority.